# API REST LINKEDIN for sourcing

Tags: javascript, html, rest, ionic3, linkedin-api

Good evening,
I want to use the LinkedIn REST API to collect information from people such as the name of the email, the experience ...
I work with Ionic 3 is based on 4 angular
With instructions in this page https: / /developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api gives no results
And with this page https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/linkedin-api-using-php-get-users-data.html he gives me an access token error
Thank you in advance if you have suggestions ...! ??
this is my code

```html
<!-- search_link.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>search</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="result_link.php">
     <input type="text" name="code">
     <input type="submit" name="">
     
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!-- result_link.php -->
   

 <?php
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$_GET['code']."&redirect_uri=http://localhost:80/linkedin_search/result_link.php&client_id={ID_CLIENT}&client_secret={SECRET_CLIENT}");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
}

if(isset($_GET['code']) && json_decode($server_output)->access_token != ''){

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=".json_decode($server_output)->access_token."&format=json");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $server_output2 = curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);

     $user_data = json_decode($server_output2);

     print_r($user_data);

}
?>
```

Comment: any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to do is, authorize the linked in app by below button

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URL}&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile">Register With LinkedIn</a>
```

it sends back a code (`$_GET['code']`) to our provided `REDIRECT_URL`.